# Chain ContinueWith Tasks at runtime

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm attempting to create a helper method for my view models which takes a collection of actions to perform and will block other collection of actions occurring at the same time.

I believe that this is a prime candidate to use `Task.ContinueWith` and my original hardcoded functionality worked without issue using this method but when I attempted to build the actions at runtime I'm hitting an issue in that my Tasks are running in different orders than I would expect.

My class looks like:

```
internal abstract class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    protected Task SynchronousTask(IList<Action> actions)
    {
        var initialTask = new Task(() => this.autoResetEvent.WaitOne());

        for (var i = 0; i < actions.Count; i++)
        {
            var i1 = i;
            initialTask.ContinueWith(task => actions[i1]());
        }

        initialTask.ContinueWith(task => this.autoResetEvent.Set());

        initialTask.Start();
        return initialTask;
    }
}
```

Essentially I want to wait on the `AutoResetEvent` blocking any new tasks running until this has been set. I then loop through each of the tasks adding them as continuations of the initial task and finally ending it with a continuation to set the `AutoResetEvent`.

In theory to me this looks like it should work, but when I run it I end up with the continuations running in the incorrect order.

I understand that there are other ways that I could do this without using the `ContinueWith`s but I'd like to see where and how I went wrong using this method.

Comment: You can get rid of all that code if you simply use `await Task.Run(action)` inside the loop. The caller will get back a Task the moment execution hits the first `await`. No need for the event or the cold tasks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah I agree that this would be better and would hope that this is what people do in the future, but my main concern was where I had went wrong, which now that I see it was a silly oversight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add multiple continuations to the same task, like in your example - they are *started* in certain order (as far as I know, that order is not documented and you should not rely on it - but it seems they are started in last in first out order), but they do not *run* in particular order. After they are started - they all run in parallel. So in your case, all actions and `autoResetEvent.Set()` will execute almost at the same time after `initialTask` has completed. If you need sequential execution - just put all that code in one `Task` and run it, no need to use `ContinueWith` here. If you really want to use `ContinueWith` - chain continuations (call `ContinueWith` on result of previous `ContinueWith`).

Comment: Ah now I see where I was going wrong I hadn't considered that I was adding all the `ContinueWith`s to the same `Task` and not 'chaining' them to the previous `ContinueWith` `Task`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is just chain to the last task, not initial task.
Imagine hooking next task to the previous one, instead of hooking all tasks to the first one.

```
public static Task SynchronousTask(List<Action> actions)
{
    var initialTask = new Task(() => autoResetEvent.WaitOne());

    Task lastTask = initialTask;
    for (int i = 0; i < actions.Count; i++)
    {
        int i1 = i;
        lastTask = lastTask.ContinueWith(task => actions[i1]()); // here
    }

    lastTask.ContinueWith(task => autoResetEvent.Set());

    initialTask.Start();
    return initialTask;
}
```